# pytorch CUDA out of memory when training on big image

Tags: pytorch

When I train a model with `512*512` images with `batch_size=4`, it works,
but when I train it with `1024*1024` images with `batch_size=1`, the `cuda` out of memory error happens.

I am confused, the total number of pixels are equal. Why one `1024*1024` image uses more memory than four `512*512` images?

Comment: I had the same problem I couldn't find any solution. Actually, I am trying to implement a paper, and even in that paper, author mentioned we cannot train using 1024*1024 or above. They tested their implementation on 2 Nvidia 1080 Ti with 2*12GB GPU memory. If you find any solution, please tell me. Thank you